# ReadWriteLock in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to be sure:
**read lock:**
If a thread is inside a read lock also another thread can enter in this read or in another read lock but any threads can enter in a write lock while 1 or more threads are in inside in a read lock.
**write lock:**
if a thread is inside in a write lock any threads can enter in a write lock or in a read lock.

Comment: There is no correlation between you being sure and how `ReadWriteLock` works.

Comment: why not ??? i think that the reply that i received is the same thing that i said no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read lock: other threads can also take a read lock, but no thread can hold a write lock.

Write lock: held by at most one thread; no threads can hold a read lock.

So: you can have one of:

- no readers or writers
- one or more readers and no writers
- no readers and exactly one writer

Comment: If by "any" you mean "no" then you read right (e.g. "if a thread is inside in a write lock [then] *no* [other] threads can enter in a write lock or in a read lock").